# react redux with asynchronous fetch

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, wait

I am using react redux, and trying to call rest-api, and return the data.
The fetch is asynchronous, and I need to return value only when the fetch is finished.

I tried the following, but this didn't work properly (there is no 'wait' on the line that is with asterisks) - What shall I do?

**Code:**

**-----**

```
var _getData = function()  
{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
    }
    let _url = "my web return json";
    fetch(_url, options)
    .then(response => 
        response.json().
            then(data => resolve({
                data: data,
                status: response.status
            }))
            .catch(err => reject(
                {error_data: err}
                )
            )

    )
    .catch(
        err =>
        {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
    )
    })
}

// ...
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
if (action.type === 'GET_DATA_FIRST') {
    let x = {}
    setTimeout(function () {
        _getData().then(
            (res) =>
            {
                x = res;
            }
        ) }, 0)
    // ******** NEED TO WAIT UTIL _getData ends and return a value ***** 


    return {
        ...state,
        myData: x
    }
}
return state;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: First off, probably don't perform async operators inside a redux reducer. Instead use an [async action](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions) creator and dispatch the action/payload to the reducer upon resolution inside then()/catch(). There are numerous middleware libraries such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to make this easy.

Comment: Can you produce me some examples, please.

Comment: You should really look at the documentation on [Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions?_sm_au_=iVVsPZWq2tkn4FH1) and [redux-thunk](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions?_sm_au_=iVVsPZWq2tkn4FH1) and restructure your actions/reducers to match the described patterns then if you are still having issues, update your question with the relevant issues. Also there are great [examples](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples) showing async redux applications. Really you would just be moving you async call to your action creator rather than the reducer.

Comment: OK. There are many documentaions. One of the documentations is as the code of mine. The code you sent is totaly different. Not ressumble the code of mine. Thank you. I will watch that.

Comment: Well. Now I got: "Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async action" even I had copied the same objects as described in the above link "Async actions". (even I did a single line: return "123"; - it failed with same error message as described.

Comment: Of course the documentation will not solve/replicate your exact issue exactly. You need to take the overall pattern of moving async actions/operations to the reducer and dispatch the resulting data from then()/catch() to the reducers. The error message is coming from lack of async middleware such as the aforementioned `redux-thunk`, there are more like this though.

Answer (score 3):

At a very basic level you need the move the asynchrounous operation out of your reducer. Instead you should trigger the `fetch()` in your action creator and dispatch an action once the `fetch()` has completed and resolved your JSON response. It would look something like the following. This example uses [redux- thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for async middleware. An additional action has been added to represent when the `fetch()` call starts and when the data is received and parsed. This can be used to show a loading message or perhaps disable and/or conditionally render specific things.

I've created a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d4y5vq).

Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware = [ thunk ];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default store;
```

Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { GET_DATA_FIRST, REQUEST_DATA } from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  myData: []
};

const things = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case GET_DATA_FIRST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        myData: action.myData
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  things // this key can be called anything, 'things' is just an example
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Action:

```
export const REQUEST_DATA = 'REQUEST_DATA'; // action to represent waiting for response
export const GET_DATA_FIRST = 'GET_DATA_FIRST'; // action to represent receiving of data

export const requestData = () => ({ type: REQUEST_DATA });

export const getDataFirst = myData => ({ type: GET_DATA_FIRST, myData });

export const fetchData = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestData());
  return getData().then(things => {
    // simulated delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      return dispatch(getDataFirst(things))
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const getData = () => {  
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(res => res.json());
}
```

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from './actions';

class ThingsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>GET DATA</button>
        {this.props.isFetching && <div>Loading...</div>}
        <ul>
          {this.props.myData.map(d => <li key={d.id}>{d.title}</li>)}
        </ul>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ things: { myData, isFetching } }) => ({
  myData,
  isFetching
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ThingsList);
```

Notice how the actions such as `fetchData()` pass `dispatch` to inner action functions. This is used to dispatch actions/payloads to the reducer. The reducer should just get ready-to-use data to update state with.

Hopefully that helps!